# tcpdump Filter with certain file types?

Tags: tcp, tcpdump

I use the unix command `tcpdump` with these extensions `-A -s0 -ien0 port 80`

I know how to add, for example a new host, that would be `and \ host random.com`

Can I sniff for certain filetypes? I have tried `filetype xml`, but that doesn't work, there must be a way to do this? Or can I at least make it more easily human readable?

But that still output things like this:

```
....@jsdiii......23............@win-concon-2---s...@@...@@
http 172. static..@@
```

And some every (25)? line there is something useful.

Answer (score 0):

tcpdump has no understanding of file types, see `man pcap-filter` for the expressions it understands. And I have no idea what exactly you want to have more human readable - maybe you should just switch to wireshark for a more comfortable interface.